# vim ident: don't remove tabs indent when closing }

Tags: vim

When I have the following in vim with cindent or vim-javascript turned on:

```
if(bla){
    #
```

(# shows cursor)

I type a new line:

```
if(bla){

    #
```

and then close the }

```
if(bla){

}
```

The problem is, now I go back up to the previous line and

```
if(bla){
#
}
```

There's no more indent after #! Now you might think this isn't annoying, but when I am working in files with multiple levels of tab indenting it destroys my productivity because of the way I code. Is there any way to make closing a } NOT destroy the tab indent before the lines?

Answer (score 2):

The tab is not deleted because you closed the `{}`, it's deleted because you didn't enter any text on that line.

I've had many variants of the following mappings in my `~/.vimrc` to "fix" that issue (waiting for a cleaner solution) for a couple of years:

```
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>==<C-o>O
inoremap {; {<CR>};<C-o>==<C-o>O
```

Both do the same thing: they close the `{}` and put the cursor where it belongs. There are a bunch of autoclosing plugins that offer that feature but I've found them too annoying in the long run.

Comment: What if I want to keep tabs even if I enter no text in a line? That's another of my habits..

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to move up to the blank line?  The arrow keys (a bad habit, according to some)?  Maybe you don't need to put in the closing brace until you've written the stuff above it?  You could also just not leave the blank line, hit the closing brace, then type `<esc>O` to open above.  Or if you like to leave the blank line for some reason just use `S` to reset the indent.